# Jquery UI Datepicker don't work after clone element

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker, clone

I have a problem with cloning an element, the jQuery UI DatePicker does't work after cloning the element. Link to example: http://jsfiddle.net/V25qA/1/.

Comment: It works for me, in which browser?

Comment: My browser is Opera 12.02. Please click 1st input , after clone element and click on cloned element.

Answer (score 2):

You can't (safely) clone jQuery widgets - they have state that may not get copied.

You should call `.datepicker('destroy')` on the old element before you clone it, and then call `.datepicker()` again on the cloned input element to reinitialise it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working fine for me in opera too.

In such cases try to delegate the event if you want this click event to work for newly created elements..

```
$('form').live('click', '.dpicker', function(){
     alert('clicked')
     $(this).datepicker().focus();  
});
```

Also I suggest you use **.on()** instead of .live() as .live is deprecated as of jquery version 1.7

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/V25qA/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line

```
$('.dpicker').eq(0).clone().prependTo('#new');
```

to

```
$('.dpicker').eq(0).clone().removeClass("hasDatepicker").prependTo('#new');
```

Then it will work.

Datepicker assigns 'hasdatepicker' class to an element when this element is datepicker-enabled via `.datepicker();`. If you clone this element, you also clone it's attributes. This is why datepicker plug-in does nothing when you call `.datepicker();`. If you remove this class datepicker will work as expected on the new element.